# Objective-C - JSON parsing values

Tags: objective-c, json

I have the following JSON that I'm trying to parse:

> {"status":"ok","post":{"id":19523,"type":"post","slug":"bennys-bar-cafe","url":"http://www.ZZZZZZZZZZ.com/2015/06/22/bennys-bar-cafe/","status":"publish","title":"Benny\u2019s Bar & Cafe","title_plain":"Benny\u2019s Bar & Cafe","content":"
>
> Wed – $10 chicken parma & chips</p>\n","excerpt":"
>
> Wed – $10 chicken parma & chips</p>\n","date":"2015-06-22 02:26:50","modified":"2015-08-24 11:18:07","categories":[{"id":15,"slug":"ZZZZZZZZZZ","title":"ZZZZZZZZZZ CSV Import","description":"","parent":14,"post_count":507}],"tags":[],"author":{"id":1,"slug":"admin","name":"admin","first_name":"","last_name":"","nickname":"admin","url":"","description":""},"comments":[{"id":11,"name":"admin","url":"","date":"2015-08-26 08:41:46","content":"
>
> Lets give this a go!</p>\n","parent":0,"author":{"id":1,"slug":"admin","name":"admin","first_name":"","last_name":"","nickname":"admin","url":"","description":""}},{"id":12,"name":"admin","url":"","date":"2015-08-26 08:42:13","content":"
>
> I like cheese</p>\n","parent":0,"author":{"id":1,"slug":"admin","name":"admin","first_name":"","last_name":"","nickname":"admin","url":"","description":""}}],"attachments":[],"comment_count":2,"comment_status":"open","custom_fields":{"City":["Perth"],"Lattitude":["-32.05505"],"Longditude":["115.747392"],"Monday Opening Time":["Nothing"],"Monday Closing Time":["Today"],"Tuesday Opening Time":["Nothing"],"Tuesday Closing Time":["Today"],"Wednesday Opening Time":["12:00 PM"],"Wednesday Closing Time":["10:00 PM"],"Thursday Opening Time":["Nothing"],"Thursday Closing Time":["Today"],"Friday Opening Time":["Nothing"],"Friday Closing Time":["Today"],"Saturday Opening Time":["Nothing"],"Saturday Closing Time":["Today"],"Sunday Opening Time":["Nothing"],"Sunday Closing Time":["Today"],"Address":["10 South Tce, Fremantle"],"Postend":["POSTEND"]}},"previous_url":"http://www.ZZZZZZZZZZ.com/2015/06/22/bells-hotel/"}

I'm using the below in Objective-C to identify the values I want to parse:

```
_postid = [dictionary objectForKey:@"id"];
_comments = [dictionary objectForKey:@"comments"];
_url = [dictionary objectForKey:@"url"];
_title = [dictionary objectForKey:@"title"];
_description = [dictionary objectForKey:@"content"]; 
_thumbnailUrl = [dictionary objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
_city = [[[dictionary objectForKey:@"custom_fields"] objectForKey:@"City"] objectAtIndex:0];
_phoneNumber = [[[dictionary objectForKey:@"custom_fields"] objectForKey:@"Phone Number"] objectAtIndex:0];
_website = [[[dictionary objectForKey:@"custom_fields"] objectForKey:@"Address"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Once I parse the data I'm able to utilize/call the objects and keys however _postid throws an error, presumably because the value associated with the "id" in the json isn't an object as it's not in double quotes - the first 2 lines of the "pretty" json version looks like this:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can parse + use the "id" value? I.e. does anyone know how to parse values that are not in double quotes?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What problem are you having with `_postid`? What is the data type of `_postid`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be an NSNumber. So you should be able to access it as

```
[_postid stringValue]
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that, definitely learned something new, even if this now does seem quite obvious - how embarassing! Thanks again, Matt